# Enum Alternative for Strings

Tags: vb.net, parsing, enums

I have the following Module that I wrote for parsing ISO currency codes into their corresponding symbols:

```
Public Module ISOCurrency
    Enum CurrencyChar
        USD = 36    ' $
        EUR = 8364  ' €
        GBP = 163   ' £
        JPY = 165   ' ¥
        BRL = 82    ' R$ - 82 gets the 'R', but not the '$'
    End Enum

    Public Function GetCurrencyFormat(ByVal customerCurrencyCode As String, _
                                      ByVal withCents As Boolean) As String
        Dim _numberFormatString As String, _currency As New CurrencyChar

        '_currency = 0 (i.e. " "c) if parse fails
        [Enum].TryParse(Of CurrencyChar)(customerCurrencyCode, _currency) 

        'These strings are derived from Excel custom number format and made to be
        '  compatible with SpreadsheetLight
        If withCents AndAlso Not _currency.Equals(CurrencyChar.JPY) Then
            _numberFormatString = "{0}* #,##0.00;[Red]{0}* (#,##0.00);{0}* ""-"";@"
        Else
            _numberFormatString = "{0}* #,##0;[Red]{0}* (#,##0);{0}* ""-"";@"
        End If

        Return String.Format(_numberFormatString, ChrW(_currency).ToString.Trim({ChrW(0)}))
    End Function
End Module
```

I can then call it like this (e.g. with a hard-coded currency):

```
Dim formatCode As String = ISOCurrency.GetCurrencyFormat("BRL", False)
```

My problem is that this is limited to single character currency symbols, and some currencies have more than one character; as in the case of Brazilian Reals.

**REQUIREMENTS**: I don't necessarily need to use an Enum, but I want the solution to be able to reference currencies as shown above: i.e. `CurrencyChar.JPY`, and also to be parseable from the ISO code string being passed in.

**EDIT**: I haven't any experience with Localization, so that's another possibility I'm willing to look into if that would be a better practice in this case.

Comment: `curChar = New RegionInfo(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JP").LCID).CurrencySymbol`

Comment: How does this get me from the ISO code string? e.g. JPY => curChar, as in your example.

Comment: the easy way would be to create a dictionary to convert ISO to culture code.  the long way would be to write a query to find the culture using that code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a dictionary instead of a enum

```
Dim currencyInfo = new Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"USD", "$"}, {"EUR", "€"}}
```

To go a bit further, you can add formatting inside a class.

```
Dim currencyInfo = new Dictionary(Of String, CurrencyInfo)

Class CurrencyInfo
    Public Property Symbol As String
    Public Property Format As String
End Class
```

Culture work with by specifying a [Language Culture Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx) which might be difficult in your case if you are interested in a specific currency instead of a currency for a language/country.

```
    Dim culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo

    culture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", False)
    Console.WriteLine(culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol)

    culture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja-JP", False)
    Console.WriteLine(culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol)

    culture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR", False)
    Console.WriteLine(culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol)
```

Comment: Ok, it seems that if I use a Dictionary that I can parse the incoming ISO Code string using something like `currencyInfo.TryGetValue(customerCurrencyCode, _currency)`. However, noting my requirements and using your suggestions, how do I reference the ISO Code such as `CurrencyChar.JPY` for easy conditional comparisons, etc.?

Comment: You would get the currency code from the dictionary: Dim currencySymbol As String = currencyInfo(customerCurrencyCode)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Attributes to do this.
I add Extension Methods to expose them more naturally.

The existing System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute works Nicely.

You may also create your own Attributes with more/additional properties.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices ' for Extension
Imports System.ComponentModel ' for Description Atttribute

Public Module ModTest

    Public Enum Names As Integer
        <Description("Bob Smith")>
        Bob_Smith
        <Description("Darren M B")>
        Darren_MB
    End Enum

Public Sub test()
    Dim x As Names = Names.Darren_MB
    Dim displayName As String = x.Description
End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Provides the Description Name for an enumeration based on the System.ComponentModel.Description Attribute on the enumeration value. if not found it returnes the defaultvalue passed.
    ''' Allows the description property of an enumeration to be exposed easily.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="EnumConstant">The Enumeration Item extended by the function.</param>
    ''' <param name="DefaultValue">Value returned when Description is not present.</param>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function Description(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum], ByVal DefaultValue As String) As String
        Dim fi As Reflection.FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
        Dim aattr() As DescriptionAttribute = DirectCast(fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())
        If aattr.Length = 0 OrElse aattr(0).Description = "" Then
            Return DefaultValue
        Else
            Return aattr(0).Description
        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Provides the Description Name for an enumeration based on the System.ComponentModel.Description Attribute on the enumeration value. if not found it returnes the Name of the Enum Item formatted (removes "_")
    ''' Allows the description property of an enumeration to be exposed easily.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="EnumConstant">The Enumeration Item extended by the function.</param>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function Description(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
        Return Description(EnumConstant, Replace(EnumConstant.ToString(), "_", " "))
    End Function

end Module
```

Comment: You would need to add a routine to support parsing of the string to the enum. Just saw that in your question now.

Comment: Intriguing concepts, but as I'm trying to implement this in my code, I'm not specifically seeing the `Description` attribute, nor is that member showing as an option in IntelliSense.

Comment: Import System.ComponentModel
I may have done this globally. Th eDescriptionAttribute is the meta data <Description("")> you see in the enum. You also need to Import the Module for the extension Description to work in other files.

Comment: Ok, I've got your code working now, except for the `Dim displayName As String = x.Description` line. Again, the `Description` member is not available for the `Names` Enum as in your case.

Comment: for a brand new project with a new module the code that is in my answer pasted in works perfectly. (I added the second imports to the answer). Is strange. Using VS2010 Pro if that makes a difference.

Comment: The "Description" functions MUST be in a Module for Extension methods to work in VB. I think you may have put it in another class.
The Enum and Test Code can be anywhere otherwise.